# wxWidgets/Python Gradient Editor?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, color-picker

This open source fractal program Fraqtive, which uses Qt, has a really cool little gradient editor for coloring your fractals:

http://fraqtive.mimec.org/node/34

Does anyone know of any nice gradient editing interfaces that use wxWidget/wxPython?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one for a fractal program I wrote in wxWidgets; I've been meaning to wrap it up nice and release on wxCode when I had time.

[image: gradient dialog]

This is inspired by photoshop's editor, so it may not be exactly what you're looking for.

The code for it is hosted here:
http://github.com/ecordell/chaostools/tree/master/src/

And the relevant files are: gradient.h, gradient.cpp, gradientdlg.h, gradientdlg.cpp

The wxGradientDialog object works just like any other dialog, and returns a wxGradient object, which uses a lerp to create the gradients from the color stops.

Answer (score 0):

Try the PyColourChooser or the CubeColourDialog